# How these static override methods are calling?

Tags: java

In this below example,Class C extends B, and B extends A.Here all the classes having a override  static methods.I know that  static method is invoked based on the compile-time type of the reference.In the method invocation expression c.m(), the compile-time type of the reference c is C. The method invocation expression c.m() invokes the method m declared in class C but in the next statement I am moving C reference to B like this B b = c; but it calling B's class static method and In the case of A also.It as to call based on reference right.

```
class Test {

    static void m() {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
}

class B extends Test {

    static void m() {
        System.out.print("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {

    static void m() {
        System.out.print("C");
    }
}

class D {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        C c = new C();
//        System.out.println("c = " + c);
        c.m();
        B b = c;
//        System.out.println("b = " + b);
        b.m();
        Test a = b;
//        System.out.println("a = " + a);
        a.m();

    }
}
```

Comment: That question Understood,But here you can see, The method invocation expression c.m() invokes the method m declared in class C but in the next statement I am moving C reference to B like this B b = c; but it calling B's class static method and In the case of A also.It as to call based on reference right.

Comment: Read the first part of [Colin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3680074/438154). The run time type of the object referenced doesn't matter when invoking `static` methods.

Comment: B b = c; this assignment will happen at run time right.

Comment: That statement (all statements) will execute at runtime. However, `static` method invocations are bound at compile time. Only the static type of `b` matters.